# The $\mathbb{C}$ vector space monad on the 2-Category of Groupoids

Tags: vector-spaces, category-theory, groupoids, monads

[In this post](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/308641/does-the-2-category-of-groupoids-admit-the-vector-space-monad), I am asking about the existence of something called the "Vector Space Monad" on the 2-Category of groupoids (Grpd).  In a comment, it was pointed out that the monad should exist due to the properties of Grpd.  I am wondering if it is possible to choose a semiring like $\mathbb{C}$, the complex numbers.  If so, I am hoping that someone would like to describe this monad on Grpd, for instance how does the functor work, how do the natural transformations work.  [Jacob's 2013 paper](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1309.0844.pdf) does this for sets.